# How to get padding mask from input ids?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, torchtext

Considering a batch of 4 pre-processed sentences (tokenization, numericalizing and padding) shown below:

```py
batch = torch.tensor([
                      [1, 2, 0, 0],
                      [4, 0, 0, 0],
                      [3, 5, 6, 7]
])
```

where `0` states for `[PAD]` token.

Thus, what would be an efficient approach to generate a `padding masking` tensor of the same shape as the `batch` assigning zero at `[PAD]` positions and assigning one to other input data (sentence tokens)?

In the example above it would be something like:

```py
padding_masking= 
tensor([
                      [1, 1, 0, 0],
                      [1, 0, 0, 0],
                      [1, 1, 1, 1]
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired result with

```
padding_masking = batch > 0
```

If you want ints instead of booleans, use

```
padding_masking.type(torch.int)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following is tested on pytorch 1.3.1.

```
pad_token_id = 0
batch = torch.tensor([
    [1, 2, 0, 0],
    [4, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 5, 6, 7]
])
pad_mask = ~(batch == pad_token_id)
print(pad_mask)
```

Output

```
tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```